# Python Script on Raspberry Pi gets error on mysql statement execution

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

### Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scheduler.py", line 27, in <module>
    cur.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 169, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, m)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple
```

Here is the code from the file:

---

```
# Get Current Weekday/Time/datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
current = datetime.datetime.today()
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now().time()

# Get Schedule Entries From Database
sql = ("""SELECT (start, stop, interrupt) FROM schedule WHERE day=%s""",(today))
cur.execute(sql)

# Use Schedule times to set / check status of pump / heater
for (start, stop, interrupt) in cur:
    if interrupt == 0 and start < currentTime and stop > currentTime:
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO status (datetime, pump, heater) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",(current, 1, 1))
    elif interrupt == 1 and start > currentTime or stop < currentTime:
        cur.execute("""UPDATE schedule SET interrupt=%s WHERE day=%s""",(0,today))
```

it says the error is on line 36 but that line is a comment (the last line of code shown above is line 34)

Comment: **update** line 36 is actually the elif statement, start and stop are of type TIME in the table

Answer (score 0):

Line 36 is the error location in the actual mysql library.  Your error is at line 27:

```
File "scheduler.py", line 27, in <module>
    cur.execute(sql)
```

cur.execute is throwing an error because you passed a tuple (ordered pair) to it.  The line

```
sql = ("""SELECT (start, stop, interrupt) FROM schedule WHERE day=%s""",(today))
```

isn't doing what you think.  It's creating a tuple from the string and the time, not formatting the string.  I think what you want is this:

```
sql = """SELECT (start, stop, interrupt) FROM schedule WHERE day=%s""" % today
```